# How to get the date from the uploaded image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

Image upload form uses following code:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="Images" title="Please upload image(Jepg, Png)" accept="image/*">
```

I would like to extract the date of the image file which i just uploaded.

```
<span id="ImageDate"></span>
```

Comment: How do you upload it? What language are you using? PHP? Your tags say `javascript` and `jquery`. But your example shows neither. Please provide more information.

Comment: Which date do you want? the EXIF date of when the image was take or the date the image was uploaded? Which is, well.. today.

Comment: Using MVC.. Yes I want the EXIF Date .

Comment: @AllenBert use `exif_read_data` http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: Can i get **jsfiddle** example ?

Comment: No, you can not get a JSfiddle example for _PHP_ functions. Plus, you should not ask for an example immediately in the first place - your own research and attempts should come before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this by using `.lastModifiedDate` in javascript

```js
$("#Images").change(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var file = this.files[i];
    var modifiedDate = file.lastModifiedDate + "<br />";
    $("#ImageDate").append(modifiedDate);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" id="Images" title="Please upload image(Jepg, Png)" accept="image/*">
<br />
<span id="ImageDate"></span>
```

Comment: Did you test this ? Wrong Date getting. Thanks Btw

Comment: @AllenBert "Wrong Date getting" what do you mean by this? It returns a date? Do you want it in a particular format?

Comment: No problem! :-)